# When using Select2, field gets too narrow when there are no options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

When there are no options, the select box shrinks to too narrow width & even "No results found" appears distorted.

Refer [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iamaditya/1sfrweqk/)

```
$('#example').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select a month'
});

<select id="example" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

Any solutions?

[image]
[image]

Comment: what's wrong to give specific width?

Comment: try to give `<select id="example" multiple="multiple" style="width: 50%"></select>`

Comment: Thanks. It worked but I want something from the library itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make use of the `width` option of select2 as follow :

```js
$('#example').select2({
  placeholder: 'Select a month',
  width: "100%"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.js"></script>
<select id="example" multiple="multiple"></select>
```